# Appium: how to get application version?

Tags: appium

How can I get application version in Appium?
Is it possible? For my iOS application getPageSource() gives me Application, but it does not have "version" parameter.
Is there any other way to find out what is the app version?

Comment: could you share which page-source are you extracting here? and what are the findings that you get by that